# EKCalendar and Error Domain=NSMachErrorDomain Code=268435459

Tags: ios, calendar, ekeventkit

I am exploring EKEventKit. 
I connect my iPhone and make the calls to get the calendars installed

```
EKEventStore *eventDB = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
NSArray * calendars = [eventDB calendars ];
```

However when I log the calendars I get this error message

> "CADObjectGetIntProperty failed with error Error
>   Domain=NSMachErrorDomain Code=268435459 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Mach error 268435459 - (ipc/send) invalid destination
>   port)"

Does anybody know what this is and why I am getting it.
Thanks

Reza

Comment: Apple has mentioned this as a known bug in this -https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the issue.

I had loaded and retained an EKEventStore previously in my code. Removing one of them solved the issue

Reza

Comment: I am having the same problem, and I think it has the same root cause, I tried [store release]; to no avail, how did you actually fix it?

Comment: I am using auto reference counting in my project. On startup I create a EKEventStore that I assign to a variable, and so it is retained and then I use that EventStore for all my calendar calls.

Comment: Thank you, this was an iOS5 bug only, and now it fixed. thank you

Answer (score 2):

I got same warning log on my console

**Earlier code:**

```
"CalendarEventHandler.m"
eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];


"CalendarEventHandler.h"

@property (nonatomic,strong) EKEventStore *eventStore;
```

**Code Modified**

```
self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];//This helped me to remove warning
```

Answer (score 2):

@discussion to `EKEventStore` class `EKEventsStore.h` file says:

`"It is generally best to hold onto a long-lived instance of an event store, most likely as a singleton instance in your application."`

The same is written here: [Reading and Writing Calendar Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW1), in `Connecting to the Event Store` section:

`"An EKEventStore object requires a relatively large amount of time to initialize and release. Consequently, you should not initialize and release a separate event store for each event-related task. Instead, initialize a single event store when your app loads, and use it repeatedly to ensure that your connection is long-lived."`

So the right way to do this is:

```
@interface MyEventStore : EKEventStore

+ (MyEventStore *)sharedStore;

@end

+ (MyEventStore *)sharedStore
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static MyEventStore *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        shared = [[MyEventStore alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}

@end
```

and use it calling `[MyEventStore sharedStore]`.

This approach also fixes the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Make the instance 'eventDB' an class member variable or property can solve the problem.